# Setting a final class attribute

Tags: java, immutability, final

Is it possible to set a value for a final attribute from a Private method called from the Constructor of that Object?

```
public class FinalTest {
  private final Object a;
  //Constructor
  public FinalTest() {
    setA();
  }

  private void setA() {
    a = new Object;
  }
}
```

For the above class, compiler gives me an error saying I can't set the value for 'a' from the method.

I understand that its not possible to set value for a final variable from outside a constructor, but in the above case, I am actually doing it in a way within the constructor. So why isn't this allowed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not allowed because you ***could*** call `setA()` via some other non-constructor method later on which would violate the final protection. Since final is a *compile time* enforced operation, the compiler enforces final by forcing initialization to occur in constructors or in-line.

In your simple example, all looks good but if you later updated your class to something like the following, the problem become more obvious...

```
public class FinalTest {
  private final Object a;
  //Constructor
  public FinalTest() {
    setA();
  }

  private void setA() {
    a = new Object;
  }

  public void doSomething() {
   this.setA(); // not good because a is final
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok. Then why cant the compiler give an error then. i.e. when I am calling serA from another non-constructor method. I guess it must have something to do with the way compiler binds methods, I would like to know more.

Comment: it could but the designers thought the path of least surprise would be best. I would think it odd to add a new method (doSomething) it all of a sudden setA breaks because of how it is called.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note:  The compiler *has* to assume the worst case scenario.  By declaring an attribute "final", the compiler has to *ensure* that the attribute cannot be modified outside of the constructor.

In a case where the method is called using reflection (for example), the compiler would never see it, ever.  It's a lot easier to prove something is possible than impossible, that is why the compiler works the way it does.

Answer (score 1):

Final checking is done at compile time not at runtime time. In your case compiler can't be sure that setA would not be called from some other method.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to set the value of final variable from a private method ?
You may do it in this way :

```
public class FinalTest {
   private final Object a;
   {
      a=new Object();
   }

   //Constructor
   public FinalTest() {
   }
}
```

In this case the object will be initialized on every FinalTest initialization.